# Error in building packages in R 3.2.0: Latex error when creating PDF version

Tags: r, package

I'm doing a final check for the package I'm writing and everything has been fixed except for the manual part. My command prompt reads:

```
*checking PDF version of manual ... Warning: running command ' "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/Rcmd.exe" Rd2pdf --batch --no -preview --build-dir="C:/Users/Char/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMZeozn/Rd2pdf1f507f8958c0" --no-clean -o PACK-manual.pdf "R://PACK.Rcheck/PACK"
had status 1
WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
 ...*
```

And the last paragraph repeats a few times. I opened the `-manual.tex` file in the resulted Rcheck file. Miktex showed the error code `` *! LaTeX Error: File `Rd.sty' not found.* ``

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

As you might have already noticed, LaTeX cannot find the `Rd.sty` file. Locate it on your system and link/copy it to your LaTeX paths. An example for Mac can be found [here](https://joey711.wordpress.com/2011/07/28/adding-sweave-sty-and-rd-sty-to-your-latex-path-in-mac-os-x/). How to add folders to the LaTeX path on Miktex can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30087/how-do-i-set-the-search-path-for-miktex).

Comment: It might be a silly question; does the Rd.sty file come with R? If not where can I find it?

Comment: The `Rd.sty` comes with base R since it is needed for the creation of package documentation. Its location depends on the OS you are using. The standard install path is `R_HOME/share/texmf`.